# FileStream with FileMode.Open erases the file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file, filestream

I have a FileStream (and nothing else) that opens a file with FileMode.Open. I've made sure that the file exists and has a few kilobytes in it it before I run my code. However, after I run the code, the file is empty (0 bytes). Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim FS As New FileStream("GameList",FileMode.Open)
End Class
```

Comment: after each filestram open, close it before exit.

Comment: @MehdiRizvand Doesn't work...

Comment: You need to flush it... its important when you create an instance of filestream to do: FS.Flush() and then close it: FS.Close() OR use a Using statement.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Does'nt work either... I tried FS.Close()

Comment: Can you also post the code where you read/write and close the stream? The cause will be probably there.... Also, when you write to an existing file you'll first need to set the position in the stream to not overwrite the existing contents.

Comment: @Bigjim It is erasing the file wit just the code I wrote (no read/write), so I deleted my project and wrote **EXACTLY** the same stuff and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to read from the file, try this:

```
New FileStream("GameList", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```

Or use a StreamReader which is more easy to work with:

```
New StreamReader("GameList")
```

Comment: @Bigjim I want to read and write to the file and I'll using a BinaryReader/BinaryWriter.

Answer (score 2):

FileMode.Open starts with the file pointer at the start of the file. Try using FileMode.Append if you want to preserve the current file contents.